# Display future posts in archive

Tags: archives, wpdb

I'm using the following code to display an archive of posts.

```
<?php
// Get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

// For each year, do the following
foreach ( $years as $year ) {

    // Get all posts for the year
    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_status = 'future' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "' ORDER BY post_date DESC" );

        foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
            // echoing miscellaneous stuff
        }
}
?>
```

There it says `post_status = 'publish'`. How can I add future posts to my archive? I tried adding `AND post_status = 'future'` to both `$wpdb->get_results` entries but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "OR" instead of "AND",

```
<?php
// Get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND (post_status = 'publish' or post_status = 'future') GROUP BY year DESC" );

// For each year, do the following
foreach ( $years as $year ) {

    // Get all posts for the year
    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'future') AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "' ORDER BY post_date DESC" );

        foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
            // echoing miscellaneous stuff
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also this one works:

```
function wpsites_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_status', array('publish','future') );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_query' );
```